# Javascript regex to remove unmatched closing HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, parsing, element

I'm trying to remove the excessive closing tags in javascript and anything that follows after that.

Here is a possible sample:

```
<div class="dummy">
    <div class="main">
        <div></div>
        <img src="a.jpg">
        <br>
        <img src="b.jpg />
        <strong>
            <span>text</span>
        </strong>
    </div>
</div>
    ***excessive tags below***
</div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    text
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas about how to do it efficiently?
The part I want to extract is always a div, but the problem is that it may have as many nested divs, and I'm not sure how to deal with this scenario.

If it can be done in multiple steps or with callbacks is also fine, as long as it works.

**Edit**
My question is actually easier than it seems.
The sample always starts with the div that I want to extract.
So all I need is to find the matching  closing tag, and filter anything that follows.
Don't care about any other tags...

Comment: Here is a terrific answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/135078

Comment: Regex is not a parsing tool.

Comment: What, precisely, are the tags you want to remove? Everything below the excessive tags below  comment? The tow unmatched tags keeping the footer div?

Comment: I did parse with Jquery before but the performance is awful. I think matching the beginning and the end of a div is more than doable in javascript.

Comment: Basically I want to remove anything that follows the div class "dummy" in this example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: A better question would have been: Does anyone know of a HTML parser that discards unnecessary tags at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data='<div class="dummy"><div class="main"><div></div><img src="a.jpg"><br><div></div><img src="b.jpg /><strong><span>text</span> </strong></div><div><div></div></div><div><div></div></div></div>***excessive tags below***</div></div><div class="footer">text</div></body></html>';



var starting_tags = [];
var closing_tags = [];

        var startIndex, index=0;
    var searchStrLen = 4;
    while ((index = data.indexOf('<div', startIndex)) > -1) {
        starting_tags.push(index);
        startIndex = index + searchStrLen;
    }
    index,startIndex=0;
    searchStrLen = 6;
     while ((index = data.indexOf('</div>', startIndex)) > -1) {
        closing_tags.push(index);
        startIndex = index + searchStrLen;
    }

    var nest_level=0;
    for (var i=0; i<closing_tags.length && nest_level<closing_tags.length && nest_level<=closing_tags.length; ++i) {
      for (var j=0+nest_level; j<starting_tags.length; ++j) {
                if (starting_tags[j]<closing_tags[nest_level]) 
            nest_level++;
      }
    }
result = data.substr(startIndex[starting_tags], closing_tags[nest_level-1]+6);    

console.log(nest_level);
console.log(starting_tags);
console.log(closing_tags);
console.log(result);
```

I was able to solve it. The code above calculates the level of div nesting, and then chops it off if it finds excessive closing tags.

https://jsfiddle.net/89j7yakz/2/

Comment: Looks like a lot of overhead for no gain over just manipulating the DOM.

Comment: Oh believe me there is a huge gain. This script runs in 0 ms, so I'm more than happy.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use regex, from my understanding, you want to retain the dummy class div and the footer class div so why not replace the body with that?

E.g.

```
var dummy = document.getElementsByClassName('dummy')[0];
var footer = document.getElementsByClassName('footer')[0]

var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
body.innerHTML = '';
body.appendChild(dummy);
body.appendChild(footer);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1kq11ry2/

Comment: Those are not physical elements. They don't exist in DOM and I'm just parsing a string. And no I don't actually need the footer. Only the dummy div.

Comment: Could you create a html element, set the content of it to be the string and then run the JS against that?

Comment: Great answer! Good doge! Basically the cleanest route to deal with a problem like this.

Comment: Nope, you are creating DOM elements, which you won't even use. This will significantly hit your performance. If I didn't care about performance I could as well render the whole page and then run a jquery selector on it. This is how I tried it first. It was actually a one-liner, but it's unaccectable performance for a bot, so I've different answer.

Comment: The leading browsers, even mobile browsers, interact with the DOM incredibly efficiently and could also handle this task in 0ms.

Comment: I don't think so